# Suspicious Files in /dev

Tags: xubuntu

Does anyone know anything about these files? I installed rootkit hunter and greped all the warnings to the screen and these showed up.

```
Warning: Suspicious file types found in /dev:
         /dev/shm/pulse-shm-3483146788: data
         /dev/shm/pulse-shm-126342462: data
         /dev/shm/pulse-shm-1687048753: data
         /dev/shm/pulse-shm-2511640061: data
         /dev/shm/pulse-shm-4166276779: data
         /dev/shm/pulse-shm-1215549193: data
```

Answer (score 4):

Those are likely false positives. You probably used rhunter with pulse audio active.

`/dev/*shm*` are SHared Memory devices and are used as a mounted file system which uses virtual memory (instead of a persistent storage device).

Those you show are related to pulseaudio to buffer audio output. Looks like pulseaudio did not do a good job at cleaning them up.

Do a ...

```
pulseaudio --cleanup-shm
```

to clean them up. See

```
pulse-daemon.conf
```

and its man page on how to manage these (disable, enable and the maximum size they can be).